# polymer dom-repeat sort finished event

Tags: polymer-1.0

How to know when sorting is done?

Polymer template example:

> ```
>    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}" sort="{{_sort(sortKey, sortAsc)}}" > <!-- change of _sort() args triggers sorting -->
>         {{item}}
>     </template>
> ```

_sort() method is invoked when either *sortKey* or *sortAsc* changes.
*list* is sorted and displayed properly.
I have observers to watch when *sortKey* or *sortAsc* changes, this happens before sorting, so they are useless.

Observer on *list* does not fire after sorting.
I need to know when sorting has been done and I can process the sorted *list*.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `dom-change` event that will be fired at the end of the rendering, therefore after the sort and/or filter function(s) have been called.

There is no specific event concerning the sort function itself.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html#L461

Comment: I wired a dom-change event as you suggested. It fires after the list is sorted (good), but it fires 34 times (bad) in my case. (test List had 57 items) 
Looks like I will not be able to use dom-repeat template for sorting. 
I will have to sort list in JavaScript, then use resulted sorting list and dom-repeat templat will be updated.

Comment: yeah... this is currently the best you can do sadly... you can always raise an issue on GH to address this need! :)

Comment: I asked this question on polymer.slack.com and got a suggestion to use debounce. dom-change stopped firing multiple times, but the idea of setting an arbitrary timeout is more like hacking with setTimeout()

Comment: I saw your post on slack (a bit late), and yes, didn't think about debounce at the time I answered you, but yes, this seems a good compromise!

Comment: sorry for the confusion:
the list is NOT sorted after dom-change event. The original Array has different order than the list in template dom-repeat, that fooled me to think that the list is sorted. I will post the solution to this problem later.
Debouncing and dom-repeat is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I learned that there is no "sort finish" event because it would be useless.
Here is what is going on in Polymer:

1. user interface is handled by `<template is="dom-repeat" sort="{{_sort(sortKey)}}">` the sorting here will affect ONLY the displayed list in the template. The JavaScript Array, which is the source of the list remains unchanged - not sorted.
2. JavaScript code has to perform `Array.sort()` method on the list, so the list will be actually sorted. The JavaScript sorting can be fired by watching change in the `{{sortKey}}` value, then the sorted list can be processed further.

Looks like a duplication, but this is the only solution I can find so far.

---

Polymer rocks!

I am rewriting application originally done in AngularJS. The ng-repeat would take 42sec to render my list of 1000 items, Polymer does it in a fraction of a sec!